# How To Get only the children of the parent category by parent id that show in shop in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, code-snippets

I have 3 parent categories: one, two, and three. Inside the 'one' category, for example, there are 'first-one', 'second-one', 'third-one', and so on. The same goes for the 'two' category, where we have 'first-two', 'second-two', 'third-two', and so on. When displaying one of the parent categories, I want to show a list (

) of only the child categories associated with it

examle what i want to show

in shop page of parent two:

```
<h3>Category two </h3>
<ul>
<li>first-two</li>
<li>second-two</li>
<li>third-two</li>
</ul>
```

and when we open  second-two Sub category
the list item will be

```
<h3>Category two </h3>
<ul>
<li>first-two</li>
<li style="color:red;margin-left:5px">second-two</li>
<li>third-two</li>
</ul>
```